# Get path from RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Let's say I have an array of paths I'm loading through Require...

```
var paths = ['libs/one','libs/two','libs/three'];
```

And I'm passing them into require as such...

```
require(paths, function(){

    for (var i=0, max=arguments.length; i<max; i++){
        someObject[CURRENT_PATH] = arguments[i];
    }

});
```

Is there a way to get the paths in the `function(){ ... }` so I can use them? I can loop through arguments, but it just gives me the contents of the `define()`'s.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague; not sure I understand. But inside the function you can still reference the `paths` variable.

Comment: I'm going to be passing the path into an object (update the example). Also, I will remove the `/` from the path, I know that would cause issues...

Comment: As Simon said, you still have access to the paths array inside require callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it seems like you want:

```
someObject[paths[i]] = arguments[i];
```

You could wrap the code to avoid any global scope as normal:

```
(function() {
    var paths  = ['libs/one','libs/two','libs/three'];

    require(paths, function () {

        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            someObject[paths[i]] = arguments[i];
        }    
    });
})();
```

Comment: I use this same approach for loading dynamic dependencies, but I should note that some browsers do not like this.  In our remote JS error logger, I see "arguments is not defined" errors pretty frequently.  Yeah... makes no sense to me either.  I haven't isolated which browsers this occurs in yet, though, but I'll try to post here when I have more info.